# Accessing a combobox inside a ToolStrip

Tags: c#

I have a ContextMenuStrip for a right-click context menu. Inside is a ToolStripMenuItem that contains a ToolStripItem array. Inside the array is a dynamically created ToolStripComboBox.

The issue I am having is that I cannot access the meat of the combobox. It has been linking to a databinding through the ComboBox. A general version of the code is below.

```
myToolStripComboBox.ComboBox.DataSource = enumList;
ToolStripItem[] toolStripItems = new ToolStripItem[1];
toolStripItems[0] = myToolStripComboBox;
ToolStripMenuItem sortOrder = new ToolStripMenuItem("Sorter", null, toolStripItems);
rightClickPopupMenu.Items.Add(sortOrder);
```

Looking through the debug shows that the datasource is indeed still set and I have all the required values, but the right-click context menu refuses to show anything but a blank combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the local c# wizard at work look at it. Something along the lines of the databinding not being called by a proper parent object.

The solution was to just directly add the times to the combo box items.

```
dropDown.ComboBox.Items.Add(enum);
```

So what I have done is make a list of the enum objects and done a foreach to add them all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
private void chData_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {   
        //your combobox binding Code

        tooltip.SetToolTip(cmdfoo, tipInfo);

    }
    catch { }
}
```

This is just a simple example.